# Does df.write.jdbc handle JDBC pool connection?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

Do you know if the following line can handle jdbc pool connection:

```
df.write
  .mode("append")
  .jdbc(url, table, prop)
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *think* so.

`spark.read.jdbc` requests Spark SQL to create a [JDBCRelation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRelation.scala#L103). Eventually [buildScan](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRelation.scala#L120) is executed that in turn calls `JDBCRDD.scanTable` that leads to [JdbcUtils.createConnectionFactory(options)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L160) for `JDBCRDD`.

With that, you see [driver.connect(options.url, options.asConnectionProperties)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L62) and unless `driver` deals with connection pooling Spark SQL does not do it.

(just noticed that you asked another question)

`df.write.jdbc` is similar. It leads to `JDBCRelation` again that uses the same RDD.

Comment: I've been looking for something that can handle connection pool in spark structured streaming. Any suggestions?

Comment: @HaoWang What would be the use case? Can you describe it in another question?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have similar use case with Spark Structured Streaming where I am reading from Kafka, doing some processing and finally writing micro-batch to Oracle inside foreachBatch loop. Right now a new connection is created for each task and I am wondering how can I avoid that.

Comment: @conetfun Use Scala `object` feature to manage a pool of connections. With that, the JVM of an executor will load the object and create the pool for every task that is scheduled for this executor. The number of executors is the number of connection pools then.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thank you. Do you have any reference article or code to refer. Sorry, but I am quite new to scala or programming in general.